# Unity3d and C# plugin for image modification

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have a plugin for Unity3D in which I need to transfer `Color[]` (from `.getPixels()` method). I do not need to modify the values of the Array, I just need to take some elements of the initial array and transfer these back like new array of the `Color[]` type in other sequence.

The point is - when I write the plugin I cannot use `Color[]` type because it is Unity3D specific type. Maybe it is possible to transfer initial array to plugin as an array of objects without specifying of exact type or something like this?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own class. `Color` is basically just a `Vector4` which is fairly easy to design. So just make your own `Vector4` which implicitly converts to and from a Unity `Color`.